# is accessing an element in an array slower than accessing a variable?

Tags: optimization

when optimizing my code, i find myself often writing something like the following ...

```
do i = 1,n
    r = t(i)
    y(i) = r*r*2.0
    f(i) = r*3.5
enddo
```

what i am doing with my variable, `r` is really irrelavent except that it is used more than once, and is most likely used as many as 5 or 6 times. now, in my head, i do this because i figure that accessing an array is slow and i want to store that variable so that i can retrieve it faster the next time. is this a correct line of thinking though? i wonder if, since i have used t(i), it is just as easy to reference in short succession as it is to reference `r` again. does storing a value from an array into a temporary variable make it quicker to us that value again, or is it just the same as if i had written

```
do i = 1,n
    r = t(i)
    y(i) = t(i)*t(i)*2.0
    f(i) = t(i)*3.5
enddo
```

? if they are the same, then i am actually slowing things down by writing an extra assignment (`r = t(i)`).

Comment: CPU dependent, compiler dependent, optimization level dependent, pipelining dependent, vectorization system dependent, the list just goes on and on. The days when you could look at a code and know how fast it would be have passed.

Comment: Computational science does not preclude experimentation. As much as experimentalists are treated as distinct from computational scientists, we too have to formulate hypotheses and test them with experiments. Experiment with different equivalent ways of writing your code. Profile the code, and also instrument your code. (PETSc has some tools for this purpose; another such library is [TAU](http://tau.uoregon.edu/).) The UNIX `time` command and the [poor man's profiler](http://poormansprofiler.org/) are also useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best thing to do is to first write the code in the most readable form
(helps understanding and debugging, and making changes long after the code was written), and then use a profiler (on the machine where you intend to use the code) to find out where the most costly statements are, and how the time is affected by altering these.

Pieces of code that are not among the most costly need not be optimized at all, as the savings is minor, and readability suffers.

Comment: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%." -- Donald Knuth, [Structured Programming With Go To Statements](http://pplab.snu.ac.kr/courses/adv_pl05/papers/p261-knuth.pdf)

Answer (score 8):

Provided there is not possible aliasing (prohibited by Fortran), any modern compiler should interpret these as being identical. You should use whichever you find easier to read or examine in a debugger.